# devise secret key error when running on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So when I run my rails app to production this is the error I get.

```
Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6 application starting in production 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:500:in `raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)

  config.secret_key = 'f6dbc12123ce33cd562fc509021181d873aa36e8162c7c45d6a862ad131975e9ab33c3b9c2e56a4f0853e44947e351654bef1cbdb555140adfb69999697268dd'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:228:in `devise_for'
    from /var/www/events_platform/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `eval_block'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:418:in `draw'
    from /var/www/events_platform/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `reload_routes!'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/lib/devise/rails.rb:17:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `block in execute_hook'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    from /var/www/events_platform/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:in `new'
    from config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/www/events_platform/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /var/www/events_platform/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /var/www/events_platform/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I've looked at every solution in stackoverflow but I still was not able to get an answer, so please do not flag this question as a duplicate, I could not find solve my issue looking at other posts in stackoverflow.

## secrets.yml

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

## devise.rb

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
  config.secret_key = ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY'] if Rails.env.production?
```

Comment: What is `Rails.env`? What is `ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY']`? Are you setting both of those values correctly? (Where are you setting them? How are you verifying them?)

Comment: They were preset with devise so I'm not to sure

Comment: An `ENV` variable does not get "preset". That's something you need to configure yourself.

Comment: I don't remember configuring it however, any steps you would suggest in this fixing this error however?

Comment: How is your production application set up? (A standard ubuntu machine? Through Heroku?...) On way or another, you need to set an environmental variable. (Or, change that file to not reference an `ENV` variable.)